# Interactive Pop gesture do not works when I present a viewcontroller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, interactivepopgesture

I have a Tab bar controller which consists of 4 tabs and each Tab contains a navigation controller . When i present a view controller on any tab and after dismissing when i try to push then interactive pop Gesture do not works till I do not change the Tab.
For Example when I present a view controller B from A and now dismiss it, Now I Push to C from A (A -> C) now interactive pop gesture should work because I have set this property in View Controller A , but when i try to swipe then the view controller pops at once and no animation is seen. Also pushing again to View Controller C does not call viewDidAppear Method. This problem continues till I change my Tab.
Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was a very simple and silly mistake that I had done in TabBarController class. The super method of viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear were not called due to which this problem was faced.